# Outlook 2013: Missing Second Calendar

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, gmail-imap

I am using Outlook from Microsoft Office 2013 with a GMail IMAP account.  At one point, I had 2 calendars showing on the Calendar tab.  Somehow I deleted or hid 1 calendar.  Currently, only 1 calendar `Calendar (This computer only)` is showing on the Calendar tab.  However, all of the appointments of the hidden calendar will show reminders.  How do I show the hidden calendar and then delete it or at least all of the appointments in it?

Comment: From the Calendar tab, on the left side open 'My Calendars' and all other tabs beneath it so that they are expanded. Let us know if your calendar is there or what you happen to see.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem but the solution is quite drastic.  First, I backed up my tasks.  The mail, calendar and people are already backed up by other mechanisms so I didn't back up those.  Here are the steps do the the backup.

1. In Outlook 2013, click on `File`.
2. Click on `Open & Export`.
3. Click on `Import/Export`.
4. Select `Export to a file` and click on `Next >`.
5. Select `Outlook Data File (.pst)` and click on `Next >`.
6. Expand the tree, select `Tasks (This computer only)` and click on `Next >`.
7. Specify a file name, select `Allow duplicate items to be created` and click on `Finish`.
8. Specify a password or leave blank.  Click on `OK`.

Once all of your data is safely backed up, close Outlook and delete the data file.  Here are the steps:

1. Open `Control Panel`.
2. Click on `Mail` (note the name may not match exactly).
3. Click on `Data Files...`.
4. Take note of the location of the data file.
5. Close `Account Settings` window.
6. Close `Mail Setup` window.
7. Open `Windows Explorer`.
8. Navigate to the folder with the data file.
9. Delete the data file.
10. Redo steps #1 to #3.
11. Re-create the data file.

Open Outlook.  Use the following steps to restore the data from backup.

1. In Outlook 2013, click on `File`.
2. Click on `Open & Export`.
3. Click on `Import/Export`.
4. Select `Import from another program or file` and click on `Next >`.
5. Select `Outlook Data File (.pst)` and click on `Next >`.
6. Expand the tree, select `Tasks (This computer only)` and click on `Next >`.
7. Specify a file name, select `Allow duplicate items to be created` and click on `Finish`.
8. Specify a password or leave blank.  Click on `OK`.